# ternary conditional ?: objective c example

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c. The following code is from GCC as i have searched:

```
int a = b ?: c;
```

Is this equivalent to

```
if (!b) //if b variable its not zero
{
a=b;
}
else
{
a=c;
}
```

Am i thinking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, I declare default `b` and `c` variables:

```objectivec
int b = 0;
int c = 1;

int a = b ?: c;
```

> `a = 1` in this case. Otherwise, if b is not zero a will take b as a result.

It will equal to this:

```objectivec
if (!b) {
    a = c;
} else {
    a = b;
}
```

Comment: It's not about nil except incidentally. It's about zero. This fails to answer the question, which is about int.

Comment: you right, I edited my answer. It's just about conditional operator.